# Comparing two lists in python if elements exist

Tags: python

I have two lists where I want to check if elements from a exists in b

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6,7,8,1]
```

This is what I tried ( didn't work though!)

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[4,5,6,7,3,1]

def detect(list_a, list_b):
    for item in list_a:
        if item in list_b:
            return True
    return False  # not found

detect(a,b)
```

I want to check if elements from a exists in b and should set a flag accordingly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Problem is that you `return True` as soon as you find the _first_ element that is in both `a` and `b`

Comment: Do you need a list of flags to check one-by-one if an element of a exists in b, or only one bool if ALL elements of a exist in b?

Comment: Flag should be raised only when all elements in a exist in b.

Comment: Use the correct data structure, use http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code returns as soon as first element exists in both lists. To check all elements you could try this for example:

```
def detect(list_a, list_b):
    return set(list_a).issubset(list_b)
```

Other possibility, without creating a `set`:

```
def detect(list_a, list_b):
    return all(x in list_b for x in list_a)
```

And in case you were curious what exactly in your code is wrong, this is the fix in its current form (but it's not very *pythonic*):

```
def detect(list_a, list_b):
    for item in list_a:
        if item not in list_b:
            return False       # at least one doesn't exist in list_b

    return True   # no element found that doesn't exist in list_b
                  # therefore all exist in list_b
```

And finally, your function name isn't very readable. `detect` is too ambiguous. Consider other more verbose names, like `isSubset` etc.